# Python - Combine two, single column lists into one dual column list and print

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, beautifulsoup

I'm just beginning to dabble with Python, and as many have done I am starting with a web-scraping example to try the language. 
I have seen many examples of using zip and map to combine lists, but I am having issues attempting to have that list print. 
Again, I am new so please be gentle.

The code gathers everything from 2 certain tag types (the date and title of a post) and returns them as 2 lists. For this I am using BeautifulSoup and requests. 
The site I am practicing on for this test is the blog for a small game called 'Staxel'

I can get my code to print a full list of one tag using [soup.find] and [print] in a for loop, but when I attempt to add a 2nd list to print I am simply getting a termination with no error. 
Any tips on how to correctly print the 2 lists?

I am looking for output like

*Entry 2019-01-06 New Years*

*Entry 2018-11-30 Staxel Changelog for 1.3.52*

```
# import libraries
import requests
import ssl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# set the URL string
quote_page = 'https://blog.playstaxel.com'

# query the website and return the html to give us a 'page' variable
page = requests.get(quote_page)


# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in a variable ... 'soup'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

# Remove the 'div' of name and get it's value
title_box = soup.find_all('h1',attrs={'class':'entry-title'})
date_box = soup.find_all('span',attrs={'class':'entry-date published'})
titles = [title.text.strip() for title in title_box]
dates = [date.text.strip()for date in date_box]
date_list = zip(dates, titles)
for heading in date_list:
    print ("Entry {}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your query for dates is returning an empty list, so the `zip`ped result will also be empty. To extract the date from that page, you want to look for tags of type `time`, not `span`, with class `entry-date published`:

[image]

like this:

```
date_box = soup.find_all("time", attrs={"class": "entry-date published"})
```

So with the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

quote_page = "https://blog.playstaxel.com"
page = requests.get(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

title_box = soup.find_all("h1", attrs={"class": "entry-title"})
date_box = soup.find_all("time", attrs={"class": "entry-date published"})
titles = [title.text.strip() for title in title_box]
dates = [date.text.strip() for date in date_box]

for date, title in zip(dates, titles):
    print(f"{date}: {title}")
```

The result becomes:

```
2019-01-10: Magic update – feature preview
2019-01-06: New Years
2018-11-30: Staxel Changelog for 1.3.52
2018-11-13: Staxel Changelog for 1.3.49
2018-10-21: Staxel Changelog for 1.3.48
2018-10-12: Halloween Update & GOG
```

Comment: Sorry, yes, the type 'span' rather than 'time' was a mix-up on my end. I had actually had that running previously with correctly returned results. The revelation here for me was the last -for- loop where date and title were called and then explicitly stated in the print command. Thanks for the code correction. Very helpful.